# Why is this loop giving me an arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when scanning an image?

Tags: arrays, image-processing, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm currently trying to figure out some code to get an image to flip horizontally by changing the taking the rgb values of each pixel and putting them into an array. I managed to get this to work for flipping images vertically, but I can't for the life of me get it to work horizontally. I can't figure out why I keep getting an outOfBoundsException. Worth noting, this code does work with square images, but not rectangular. So my code is

```
int width = selection.getWidth();
int height = selection.getHeight();
int rgb[][] = new int[height][width];
int rgb2[][] = new int[height][width];

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        rgb[i][j] = selection.getRGB(i, j);
        rgb2[i][j] = selection.getRGB(i, j);
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

From debugging it by reading values of small arrays and testing this loop, I can't figure out what's going on. I tried doing a few values by hand and it seems like it should scan row by row, creating a 2d array of the same height and width of the image with the pixel values. However, it never gets out of the inner loop. Something in the inner loop is out of bounds.

Even doing

```
for (int i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rgb[0].length; j++) {
            rgb[i][j] = selection.getRGB(i, j);
            rgbTwo[i][j] = selection.getRGB(i, j);

        }
    }
```

It still says that a coordinate is out of bounds. I can't figure out why this isn't working for horizontal but it is for vertical, and it works for squares but not rectangles. My vertical flip works for both squares and rectangles.

Comment: It looks like `i` and `j` are backwards. Width should be first shouldn't it for `getRGB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `getRGB(i, j)` with `getRGB(j, i)`. The x value comes before the y value. (See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)))

Comment: Thanks so much. I had 3 different loops with that problem and that was the issue.